# OAuth2 blocks access to external service ("XMLHttpRequest cannot load firestore due to access control checks")

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-firestore, access-control

I am facing a problem having to do with the interplay between firebase and a REST server that is secured by OAuth2.

If the REST server is started without authentication enabled everything works fine.

However, if the REST server is started with authentication enabled, then the communication between the Angular frontend and firebase is disturbed.

The architecture of the application looks as follows:
The frontend consists of an Angular application. The backend consists of two parts: firebase and a REST-server (whereby the REST server is again connected to a Hyperledger-fabric-blockchain ... but this is not relevant for this question).

If authentication is not enabled for the REST-server, then communication between the Angular frontend and the REST server AND communication between the Angular frontend and firebase (which is used to store certain master data of users and pictures) is working perfectly fine.

However, with authentication enabled for the REST server, the Angular Frontend can no longer call firebase.

The following error message appears in the console:

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load [https://firestore......] due to access control checks."
```

see the following screenshot from the console:

[image]

How can I fix this?

---

UPDATE:

I changed the Rules for firestore from:

[image]

to

[image]

However, I still get the same error message.
That means, somehow OAuth2 (which is between the frontend and the REST server) prevents the angular frontend from accessing firestore (which has noting to do with the REST server or OAuth2).

---

---

Detailed explanation (may not be necessary to read):

Let me explain the problem in more detail by means of what's happening in my AuthService.

This is the beginning of file auth.service.ts:

```
export class AuthService implements OnDestroy {


    private idOfCurrentUser: string;
    private roleOfCurrentUser: string;
    private user: Observable<User>;
    private subscription1: Subscription;
    private subscription2: Subscription;



    constructor(private router: Router, private db: AngularFirestore, private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth, private httpClient: HttpClient, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

        this.user = this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(
            switchMap(user => {
                if (user) {
                    return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
                } 
                else {
                    return of(null);
                }
            })
        );


        this.subscription1 = this.user.subscribe(participant => {
            console.log("With authentication enabled, THIS DOES NEVER GET PRINTED");                
           if (participant) {
                this.idOfCurrentUser = participant.id;
                this.roleOfCurrentUser = participant.role;
            }
            else {
                this.idOfCurrentUser = "admin";
                this.roleOfCurrentUser = "NetworkAdmin";
            }
        });


//subscription2 only plays a role, if authentication for the REST server is enabled. 
        this.subscription2 = this.activatedRoute
                            .queryParams
                            .subscribe(queryParams => {

                                let authenticated = queryParams['authenticated'];
                                if (authenticated) {
                                    this.router.navigate(['']);
                                    return this.getContentOfWalletOfCurrentUser()
                                        .then(result => {
                                            if (result.length > 0) {
                                                console.log("The user already has a business network card.");
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                while(this.idOfCurrentUser == null || this.roleOfCurrentUser == null) {
                                                    console.log("IN LOOP");
                                                }
                                                this.createBusinessNetworkCard();
                                            }
                                        });  
                                }
                            });


    }
```

If authentication for the REST server is NOT enabled, then subscription1 works fine and receives data for the current user (e.g. the current user's "role") from firestore.

However, when the REST server is started with authentication (GitHub OAuth2) enabled, subscription1 does NOT work. Communication between the Angular App and firebase is blocked.

As a result of that, the code is trapped within the following loop:

```
 while(this.idOfCurrentUser == null || this.roleOfCurrentUser == null) {
    console.log("IN LOOP");
}
```

... see this screenshot from the console:
[image]

Comment: Did you solve this issue ?