# Firestore snapshot not updating properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if a Firestore document snapshot is being refreshed if the function runs again.

Here I am trying to get a readout of the 'active' property which returns a boolean.

Unfortunately, if I manually change the value in the document to 'false', the readout still shows 'true', even after reloading (and supposedly re-running the function).

```
// Check if user is logged in
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        findSubscription(user);
    } else {
        console.log('logged out')
    }
})

const findSubscription = (user) => {

    // Get document
    db.collection('stripe_customers')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection('subscription_info')
        .doc('subscription_object')
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {

            // Get number of keys in document
            const numberOfKeys = Object.keys(doc.data()).length;

            // Check if numverOfKeys is > 0 (it is not if the user has never had a subscription before)
            if (numberOfKeys !== 0) {

                // Get subscription status
                const subscriptionStatus = doc.data().subscription.plan.active;
                console.log(subscriptionStatus);
```

Occasionally I am getting the following console log.

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load ('google api url') due to access control checks."

My database is still in public mode for testing so I am not quite sure what that is all about.

Comment: What do you mean "even after reloading"? You're refreshing the entire page and still getting old data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `onSnapshot()` instead of `get()` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

```
let unsubscribe = null;

const addSubscription = (user) => {
    // Subscribe to document updates 
    // (called immediately & every subsequent change) 
    unsubscribe = db.collection('stripe_customers')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection('subscription_info')
        .doc('subscription_object')
        .onSnapshot((doc) => { ... })
}
```

Comment: For understanding: Why does the get() function not show the updated values after being run again on page-refresh?

Comment: @Max - Sorry, I thought you meant updated from Firebase console. You're refreshing your page containing this code? In JS the offline cache is disabled by default so this surprises me as much as it surprises you. Perhaps CodingDoug will jump in with an answer!

Comment: Right, the code is on the page and I'd like it to rerun on page reload. Some additional information: Sometimes I am getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load ('google api url') due to access control checks." My database is still in public mode for testing so I am not quite sure what that is all about.

Comment: That does seem relevant! I can see you're not the only one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830224/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-firestore-googleapis-due-to-access-contr and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843086/oauth2-blocks-access-to-external-service-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-firestore?rq=1 -- sadly neither have an answer & I don't know :/ I recommend you update your question to note this issue.